# Netbeans Swing GUI graphic issue

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I created a Swing GUI using the NetBeans IDE GUI Builder and I experience a small graphic issue when I hover over my JButton. What is the reason of this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: What behavior? What have you tried? Can you provide code? Can you provide any specifics? Have you ever been on stackoverflow?

Comment: Could we see the code, and an idea of the graphics issue itself?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the graphic issue.

Comment: Please add the code of your implementation. This way you have more chances of getting a proper answer.

Comment: It's a blank tooltip property

Comment: See [How to use tool tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html). You should be able to get rid of it by supplying a `null` value to the `tooltip` property

Answer (score 0):

You have a tooltip.
On the properties panel - > toolTipText, open the custom editor (the button with 3 dots)
Then choose the "reset to default" button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the reference to your `JButton` object is `jButton1`, just call `jButton1.setToolTipText(null)` in order to turn the tool tip text off.